# Is there a way to move places in Final Fantasy Tactics Advance?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-advance

I was following a map, and I realized that I put Nubswood in the wrong place. I've already placed four more locations though, and I don't think that I can play the game all over again. Is there some way to fix this, or do I have no choice but to play it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no choice, once the position is placed, it is fixed for the rest of the game.  However, the end result may just be you miss out on some items, but none of the items you obtain are irreplaceable.

Comment: By irreplaceable, do you mean that no item gained by careful placing is unique and only obtainable in that way?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer by irreplaceable, I mean the items are not required to complete the game.  There are a few unique items only obtainable that way, but they don't require a specific map setup as they are obtainable via other map layouts.

Comment: http://faqs.ign.com/articles/430/430327p1.html i was using that last map layout, and misplaced nubswood to the 13 spot...is it possible to still get the genji stuff?